# Trouble rewriting an SQL query into HQL query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hql

So, here is my original query in SQL:

```
SELECT      o.offering_number,
        o.english_description,
        o.french_description,
        fop.price_amount,
        fop2.price_amount,
        fop.price_type_code,
        fop.offering_id,
        fop2.offering_id
            from facility_offering_price fop
            join offering o on fop.offering_id = o.offering_id
            inner join
                (select
                    fop1.offering_id,
                    fop1.price_amount
                            from facility_offering_price fop1
                            WHERE fop1.price_type_code = 5
                            AND fop1.price_status_code = 1
                ) fop2 on fop.offering_id = fop2.offering_id
                WHERE fop.price_start_date = '15-10-28'
                AND fop.price_status_code IN (1,2)
                /*AND (price_status_code IS NULL)*/
                AND fop.price_type_code = 5
                /*AND (o.offering_number IS NULL)*/
                    ORDER BY o.offering_number ASC, fop.price_sequence_number ASC;
```

Here is the query above in HQL:

```
    @Query("SELECT new com.frontier.dto.productprice.PendingPriceProduct("
        + " fop.facilityPhysicalOffering.offeringNumber,"
        + " fop.facilityPhysicalOffering.offering.description.englishDescription,"
        + " fop.facilityPhysicalOffering.offering.description.frenchDescription,"
        + " fop.priceAmount,"
        + " fop2.priceAmount,"
        + " fop.priceStatusCode"
        + ")"
        + " from FacilityOfferingPrice fop"
        + " INNER JOIN (SELECT fop1.offeringId, fop1.priceAmount FROM FacilityOfferingPrice fop1 WHERE "
        + " fop1.id.priceTypeCode = com.frontier.domain.type.PriceType.REG_RETAIL_PRICE"
        + " AND fop1.priceStatusCode = com.frontier.domain.type.OfferingPriceSts.CURRENT" +
        " ) fop2 on fop.offeringId = fop2.offeringId"
        + " WHERE fop.priceStartDate = :priceStartDate"
        + " AND fop.priceStatusCode IN (:priceStatusCodes)"
        + " AND (:priceStatusCode IS NULL OR fop.priceStatusCode = :priceStatusCode)"
        + " AND fop.id.priceTypeCode = com.frontier.domain.type.PriceType.REG_RETAIL_PRICE"
        + " AND (:fromOfferingNumber IS NULL OR fop.facilityPhysicalOffering.offeringNumber >=:fromOfferingNumber)"
        + " ORDER BY fop.facilityPhysicalOffering.offeringNumber ASC, fop.id.priceSequenceNumber ASC")
List<PendingPriceProduct> findPendingPriceProducts(
        @Param("priceStartDate") LocalDate priceStartDate,
        @Param("priceStatusCodes") List<OfferingPriceSts> priceStatusCodes,
        @Param("priceStatusCode") OfferingPriceSts priceStatusCode,
        @Param("fromOfferingNumber") Long fromOfferingNumber,
        Pageable pageable);
```

The error message: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 372.
So, something is wrong with the join syntax. It was all good before I replaced the subquery with this join.

I would appreciate your help.

UPDATE:

New Query:

```
    @Query("SELECT "
        + " new com.frontier.dto.productprice.PendingPriceProduct("
        + " fop.facilityPhysicalOffering.offeringNumber,"
        + " fop.facilityPhysicalOffering.offering.description.englishDescription,"
        + " fop.facilityPhysicalOffering.offering.description.frenchDescription,"
        + " fop.priceAmount,"
        + " fop1.priceAmount,"
        + " fop.priceStatusCode"
        + ")"
        + " from FacilityOfferingPrice fop"
        + " INNER JOIN FacilityOfferingPrice fop1 on fop.offeringId = fop1.offeringId"
        + " WHERE fop.priceStartDate = :priceStartDate"
        + " AND fop.priceStatusCode IN (:priceStatusCodes)"
        + " AND (:priceStatusCode IS NULL OR fop.priceStatusCode = :priceStatusCode)"
        + " AND fop.id.priceTypeCode = com.frontier.domain.type.PriceType.REG_RETAIL_PRICE"
        + " AND (:fromOfferingNumber IS NULL OR fop.facilityPhysicalOffering.offeringNumber >=:fromOfferingNumber)"
        + " ORDER BY fop.facilityPhysicalOffering.offeringNumber ASC, fop.id.priceSequenceNumber ASC")
List<PendingPriceProduct> findPendingPriceProducts(
        @Param("priceStartDate") LocalDate priceStartDate,
        @Param("priceStatusCodes") List<OfferingPriceSts> priceStatusCodes,
        @Param("priceStatusCode") OfferingPriceSts priceStatusCode,
        @Param("fromOfferingNumber") Long fromOfferingNumber,
        Pageable pageable);
```

New error:
Path expected for join!, `InvalidPathException: Invalid path: 'fop1.priceAmount'

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can write subqueries like this in HQL, and by the way, do you really need a subquery at all? If you rewrite your initial query like that

```
SELECT      o.offering_number,
        o.english_description,
        o.french_description,
        fop.price_amount,
        fop1.price_amount,
        fop.price_type_code,
        fop.offering_id,
        fop1.offering_id
            from facility_offering_price fop
            join offering o on fop.offering_id = o.offering_id
            inner join facility_offering_price fop1
              on fop.offering_id = fop1.offering_id
        WHERE fop.price_start_date = '15-10-28'
                AND fop.price_status_code IN (1,2)
                /*AND (price_status_code IS NULL)*/
                AND fop.price_type_code = 5
                /*AND (o.offering_number IS NULL)*/
                AND fop1.price_type_code = 5
                AND fop1.price_status_code = 1
       ORDER BY o.offering_number ASC, fop.price_sequence_number ASC;
```

The translation to HQL should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: thanks, that looks nice. I tried translating it to HQL but kept getting errors. Could you help me with the transation?